# Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value:

Tags: mysql, mule4

I am using mule 4.
I am trying to post data from into MySQL like this -

```
[{
    "Transaction_date": "2020-01-01",
    "Product": "car",
    "Price": 100000,
    "Payment_Type": "cardit",
    "Name": "Ahmed",
    "City": "Columbus",
    "State": "OH",
    "Country": "US",
    "Account_Created": "2020-01-01",
    "Last_Login": "2020-01-01",
    "Latitude": 1.788,
    "Longitude": 2.3939
},
{

    "Transaction_date": "2020-01-01",
    "Product": "car",
    "Price": 100000,
    "Payment_Type": "cardit",
    "Name": "Ahmed",
    "City": "Columbus",
    "State": "OH",
    "Country": "US",
    "Account_Created": "2020-01-01",
    "Last_Login": "2020-01-01",
    "Latitude": 1.788,
    "Longitude": 2.3939
}]
```

but when I send this I am getting this error.

```
Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x13java.util.ArrayListx\x81\xD2\x1D\x99\xC7a\x9D\x03\x00\x01I\x00\x04sizexp\x00\x00\x00\x02w\x04\x00\x00\' for column 'Transaction_date' at row 1
```

Can anyone can help me?

Comment: *but when I send this I am getting this error.* Show sending code.

Comment: What *exactly* is the data type of your database column?

Comment: Here is the datatype 

Transaction_date  datetime 
Product  varchar(50) 
Price  int 
Payment_Type  varchar(50) 
Name    varchar(50) 
City  varchar(50) 
State varchar(50) 
Country varchar(50) 
Account_Created datetime 
Last_Login datetime 
Latitude float 
Longitude float

Comment: @Saye - Change the type of `Transaction_date` and `Account_Created` to `DATE` if you want to store just the date and not date & time.

Comment: @ Arvind Kumar Avinash
 I did but Its the same thing. I can load a single object but I can't load array

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say to say without more details but it looks like you are trying to insert the payload, which is a list of objects, into a single database record. That will obviously will not work. Either iterate over each list member to insert it or use the bulk insert operation.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message when trying to insert `2022-07-14T04:20:29.298575Z` and similar into a MySQL `DATETIME` column - if I truncated it to `2022-07-14T04:20:29` it worked.